# How to configure the endpoints when a SOAP client was generated with VS 2019?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, visual-studio-2019

## Before 2019

I used to generate the clients to consume WCF services with Visual Studio 2017 or Rider (the behavior is the same). What happens is that the generated client inherits of `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase` and I can pass an endpoint configuration to this `ClientBase` through the generated client. The generated code looks like:

```cs
public partial class GeneratedSoapClient : ClientBase<GeneratedSoapClient>
{
    public GeneratedSoapClient (string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

That allows to add some endpoints in the host's `app.config`:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MySoap" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://dev.my_service.net?asmx"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MySoap"
              name="MyService_Dev" />

    <endpoint address="http://prod.my_service.net?asmx"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MySoap"
              name="MyService_Prod" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Then I construct my client with either `"MyService_Dev"` or `"MyService_Prod"` to call the dev or prod service.

## After 2019

With Visual Studio 2019, the code generation is different. It does not generate `svcmap` and `webref` files. Instead, it generates a single `json` file with the information.

In the C# code, the generated client does not accept an endpoint config as a string anymore, now it takes an enum, and then it resolves the endpoint directly in the code:

```cs
public enum EndpointConfiguration
{
    ServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint,
    ServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint,
}

class GeneratedSoapClient : ClientBase<GeneratedSoapClient>
{
    public GeneratedSoapClient(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration) :
        base(/* Binding, not related to my issue*/, GetEndpointAddress(endpointConfiguration))
    {
    }

    private static GetEndpointAddress(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {
        if (endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.ServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint)
        {
            return new EndpointAddress("http://prod.my_service.net?asmx");
        }
        if (endpointConfiguration == EndpointConfiguration.ServiceHttpSoap12Endpoint)
        {
            return new EndpointAddress("http://prod.my_service.net?asmx");
        }
        throw new System.InvalidOperationException(string.Format("Could not find endpoint with name \'{0}\'.", endpointConfiguration));
    }
}
```

In this situation, I cannot configure my own endpoint because I prefer not to modify the generated code as that is a bad practice. It would require to apply the same "patch" after the regeneration everytime the contract changes. In this situation,

**How should I use the newest WCF client generator to allow to configure the client endpoint?**

As a precision, I did not find any option in the wizard to keep using a string as an endpoint configuration.

Comment: Just call the constructor of `GeneratedSoapClient` with your instance of configured `EndpointConfiguration`

Comment: Great question and still no examples. What a shame. I could really use some examples

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps anyone out, but here is an actual example.  Please note the answers above are correct... just not specific enough.

I added a new 'web reference' by right clicking the project => Add => Web Reference.  When prompted, I named it EUSelfServWS and specified the wsdl url.  This generated the proxy classes which are stored in a folder named Services.

To instantiate an instance of the client:
var svc = new EAUToEUSS.PerformanceTest.Service.ServiceSoapClient(ServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.ServiceSoap);

Note the ServiceSoapClient object requires you to specify whether or not to use ServiceSoap or ServiceSoap12.  This is an enum.

To instantiate an instance with a URL:
var endpointAddr = new EndpointAddress("https://YOUR.server.com/EUSelfServWS/Service.asmx");
var svc = new EAUToEUSS.PerformanceTest.Service.ServiceSoapClient(ServiceSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration.ServiceSoap, endpointAddr);